# Javascript form submission with extra parameters / custom redirect

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I currently have a form which users can traditionally click on a submit button to save. The form action goes to a page called formProcess.php, which contains a meta-redirect that will save everything then redirect the user back to the form.

I have been requested to add a new feature to a hyperlink on the form page which will automatically save the form before following the hyperlink to a different page. I've currently got some simple jQuery connected to the hyperlink which submits the form like so:

```
$('#hyperlink').click(function() { 
    $(this).closest("#save_form").submit();
});
```

This works and submits the form, but of course formProcess.php has a meta-redirect in it which will take the user back to the form page which I don't want.

I figure if I could pass some extra parameter in the Javascript form submission, like submit('redirect=link'); then I could add something like this to formProcess.php:

```
if ($_POST['redirect'] == 'link') {
    // Redirect 1
} else {
    // Redirect 2
}
```

Is this possible? I can't seem to find any information on being able to pass any extra parameters using submit(); If not, what would you suggest is the best way to tackle my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `append` a temporary field to your form.

```
$('#hyperlink').click(function() {
    $(this).closest("#save_form").append('<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="link" />');
    $(this).closest("#save_form").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your form you can use **hidden** input type.

Ex.

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="link"/>
```

so when form is submit your hidden field value also to be submit with other parameter.

in your php you can simply do as below:

```
if ($_POST['redirect'] == "link") {
    // Redirect 1
} else {
    // Redirect 2
}
```

Comment: I thought this, but that field will be picked up by the regular submit button save too.

Comment: Means you only send it when click to particular hyperlink?

Comment: You can use append() function of jquery to add hidden field in form when user click on hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use ajax to submit your form and upon success then redirect to the url you want.Without using ajax you could add a hidden field in your form and change it's value.Then server side you ll be able to check the value of you hidden field and act accordingly.

Comment: How could I use AJAX to submit my form data? I know about the ajax() object and passing info with data but this form is a beast so I'd rather not have to pile every single form field and value into a JSON array. I don't trust myself to miss one (there are somewhere around 100 fields) and it seems like it'd be a pain to maintain going forward. Or do you mean something else with AJAX?

Comment: Did not know about serialize(). Went with a different solution for this problem but knowing about that will definitely come in handy in the future, thanks!